# how to use multiple regular expressions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want validate an input form in jquery using regular expression. I have used first regular expression variable to validate first name. But I can't use any other regular expression to validate next input variable (lname, email). When I use multiple regular expressions the jquery is not working.

Here is my HTML code

```
<p>First Name:</p><input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="Enter your first name">
    <span class= "error" id= "fnamelabel"></span>
    <p class="formname">Last Name: </p><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname"class="forms" placeholder="Enter your Last name">
    <span class="error" id="lnamelabel"></span>
    <p class="formname">Address:</p><input type="text" name="address" id="address"class="forms" placeholder="Enter your address name">
    <span class="error" id="addresslabel"></span>   
    <p class="formname">Email:</p><input type="text" name="email" id="email"class="forms" placeholder="Enter email address">
    <span class="error" id="emaillabel"></span> // four input form
```

and here is my jquery code

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#sub').click(function()
                    {
                        formvalidation();
                    });
    function formvalidation()
    {
        var namef = $('#fname').val();
        var namel= $('#lname').val();
        var address = $('#address').val();
        var email= $('#email').val();

        var namexP =/^([a-zA-Z ])*/;
        //var countryexP=   /^([a-zA-Z]+([\s-][a-zA-Z]+)$/; //here i tried to declare a regular expression
        //var emailxP = /^(\w+([0-9-+.']\w+)*+\@\w+\.([\a-z]{2,3})([.]\w+))$/;

        ////////validation for first name
        if(namef=="")
        {
            $('#fnamelabel').text('Enter your first name.');
            $('#fname').css("border","1px solid red");
        }
        else if(!namexP.test(namef))
        {
            $('#fnamelabel').text("Letters only.")
            $('#fname').css("border","1px solid red");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#fnamelabel').text('');
            $('#fname').css("border","default");
        }

        ////////validation for Last name
        if(namel=="")
        {
            $('#lname').css("border","1px solid red");
            $('#lnamelabel').text('Please enter your last name name');
        }
        else if(!namexP.test(namel))
        {
            $('#lnamelabel').text("Letters only");
            $('#lname').css("border","1px solid red");
        }
        else
        {
            $('#lname').css("border","default");
            $('#lnamelabel').text('');
        }

        ////////validation for Address
        if(address == "")
        {
            $('#address').css("border","1px solid red");
            $('#addresslabel').text('Please enter your address');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#address').css("border","default");
            $('#addresslabel').text('');
        }

        //namexP= /^([a-zA-Z]+([\s-][a-zA-Z]+)$/; 
        if(email == "")
        {
            $('#email').css("border","1px solid red");
            $('#emaillabel').text('Please enter your email');
        }
        //here I also tried to direct matching method
        /*else if(email.!match(/^(\w+([0-9-+.']\w+)*+\@\w+\.([\a-z]{2,3})([.]\w+))/))
          {
          $('#email').css("border","1px solid red");
          $('#emaillabel').text('Please enter a valid email address someone@____.com'); 
          }*/
        else
        {
            $('#email').css("border","default");
            $('#emaillabel').text('');
        }
        return false;
    });
```

All I have tried is not working. 
So Please help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: You should look into using HTML5 input validations: http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is

```
if (!email.match(<regexp>)) ...
```

not

```
if (email.!match(<regexp>)) ...
```

Actually, yo should use `test` rather than `match` if you just want to know if the match succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your regular expression pattern which does validate the mail.

Use this pattern to validate your email address.

```
var emailPattern = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

and  validate your email like

```
else if(!emailPattern.test(email){
```

OR

```
else if(!email.match(emailPattern))
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/suman_bogati/zT8D4/)

Comment: You shouldn't really be rejecting an email address if a complex regex attempting to completely validate an address doesn't work because the address could actually very well be valid. E-mail addresses simply have too many valid possibilities. I would just check for a "@" and a domain extension and require account activation on the server side.